# query to combine rows with same col value into one row with new cols based on a condition in sql

Tags: mysql

I have data in my table as:

| sku | grade | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | A | 700 |
| iphone | B | 600 |
| samsung | A | 200 |

I want to merge the rows based on the sku col and have cols as A_price and B_price based on the grade value.

The result should be:

| sku | A_price | B_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | 700 | 600 |
| samsung | 200 | null |

I have tried the below query:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN grade = 'A' THEN price end as A_price,
 CASE WHEN grade = 'B' THEN price end as B_price
FROM dataTable 
GROUP BY sku
```

But its giving me error as 'not a group by expression'.

Answer (score 0):

You could sum over a `case` expression for each column:

```sql
SELECT   sku,
         SUM(CASE grade WHEN 'A' THEN sku END) AS a_price,
         SUM(CASE grade WHEN 'B' THEN sku END) AS b_price
FROM     dataTable
GROUP BY sku
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this query :

```
select p.sku,  p.price as 'A_price', s.B_price
from products p
left join (
    select sku, price as 'B_price'
    from products
    where grade = 'B'
) as s on s.sku = p.sku
where p.grade = 'A';
```